# Why is postman showing error message but react app not showing it?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, api, postman

I am developing an API (AWS lambda function using nodejs). here I am checking if the files sent to API via HTTP POST are less than 2 MB. if they are more than that then I am raising an error.

```
import createError from "http-errors";

if (totalSize > sizeLimitInMB) {
    throw new createError.Forbidden(
      `Size of all the attachments combined should not exceed ${sizeLimitInMB} MB. The files you have submitted are ${totalSize} MB`
    );
  }
```

Now postman shows this error message correctly. But when I try to produce same situation using my react front end. I get this message instead

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'MY_API_URL' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

an error occurred  Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84)

POST 'MY_API_URL' net::ERR_FAILED
```

I am not sure why CORS error, because it works if my files are less than 2 MB. my code in react component

```
try {
      await submit(id, data);
      setSaving(false);
      history.replace("/");
    } catch (error) {
      setSaving(false);
      console.error("an error occurred ", error);
    }
```

Why is the frontend not able to console log the same error message as postman? and this is not just for this particular size error. Any other errors I throw such as "Only owner can delete this file" or "Post with this ID not found" are also not displayed in my frontend but work perfectly well in postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by changing the order of middlewares in common middleware. I had a function common middleware that used to wrap the handler

```
export const handler = commonMiddleware(myHandler);

Earlier it was
export default (handler) =>
  middy(handler).use([
    httpJsonBodyParser(),
    httpEventNormalizer(),
    httpErrorHandler(),
    cors(),
  ]);

After
export default (handler) =>
  middy(handler).use([
    cors(),
    httpJsonBodyParser(),
    httpEventNormalizer(),
    httpErrorHandler(),
  ]);
```

and it worked